# Router and redirect special

Tags: php, redirect, routes

I'm working with MVC and handling routers and am struggling to apply redirection.

**request**: site.com/christmas
**redirect**: site.com/holiday/christmas

do not think I should keep a "controller christmas" to do the redirection
My doubt is at what stage should I perform redirection?
I create a config with the special cases of redirection of separate config?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This re-write rule might help you..

This rewrites every request that come to `site.com/(anything)` to `site.com/holiday/(anything)`:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /holiday/$1
```

Just put this in your .htaccess and it will do it's job.

If you want only the `site.com/christmas` to be redirected try this:

```
RewriteRule ^christmas/?$ /holiday/christmas
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can not create these rules in htaccess. Needs to be in PHP